# Spring MVC - How can I use different timeouts for my resttemplates?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am using Spring MVC with Spring 3.1.  I have a web application that uses many REST services.  One of these REST services takes up to an hour to respond - which I can not change.  I have my timeout for the RestTemplate set up like this with the timeout set to 60 minutes:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate ">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
            <property name="readTimeout" value="3600000" />
            <property name="connectTimeout" value="3600000" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I would like to be able to set all of my other REST calls to a different set of timeouts.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this on a method call basis. In other words, all calls on the `restTemplate` bean will use the same underlying `ClientHttpRequestFactory`. If you want different requests to use different timeout values, declare multiple `RestTemplate` beans and inject the appropriate ones in your beans.

Comment: Is the situation still the same? Your answer is more than 4 years old now, maybe Spring has some updates?

Comment: @HonzaZidek Looking at the current [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) API, I don't see anything that would allow you to set a timeout per request.